# flask_sqlalchemy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to create a database for a flask application. To do this, I created a separate temporary file tmp.py it contains the following code.

```
from src import db, create_app

db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

After the launch tmp.py The following error appears in the file

```
src is the source folder with .py files When trying to run tmp.py An error appears in the file Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/src/tmp.py", line 3, in \<module\>
db.create_all(app=create_app())
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/src/__init__.py", line 14, in create_app
db.init_app(app)
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 374, in init_app
engines\[key\] = self.\_make_engine(key, options, app)
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 665, in \_make_engine
return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 803, in engine_from_config
return create_engine(url, \*\*options)
File "\<string\>", line 2, in create_engine
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
return fn(\*args, \*\*kwargs)  # type: ignore\[no-any-return\]
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 601, in create_engine
dbapi = dbapi_meth(\*\*dbapi_args)
File "/home/goodstealing/PycharmProjects/tFlusk/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 505, in import_dbapi
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in \<module\>
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import \*
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in \<module\>
from \_sqlite3 import \*
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_sqlite3'\`
```

Below I attach the database initialization function and create
db initialization

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
app.config\['SECRET_KEY'\] = 'secret-key'
app.config\['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'\] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)
    
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    
    return app
```

db create

```
from . import db

class User(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(100))
password = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

I tried reinstalling flask_sqlalchemy, tried creating a database through the console using python3.10.13

Comment: Your Python installation has not been compiled with support for sqlite. The linked duplicate describes a number of ways that you might fix this: if you are using Ubuntu or similar, installing the sqlite header library package and then reinstalling Python using apt is probably the safest approach.  Note that there are many questions about this error message on Stack Overflow.